# Quotes around strings in sqlite query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a db made with this statement:

```
DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_BANDS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
        + " text unique not null, " + COLUMN_GENDER + " text, " + COLUMN_POPULARITY + " real not null);";
```

I add to it a row with this statement:

```
private long addBand(String bandName, String gender) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "\"" + bandName.trim().toLowerCase() + "\"");
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_POPULARITY, 1);
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_GENDER, "");
    long insertId = database.insert(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_BANDS, null,
            values);

    return insertId;
}
```

I get insertId > 0, so I think that the insertion was ok.

Then I try to select a row that I just inserted with this code:

```
public Band getBand(String name) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_BANDS,
            new String[] {BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_POPULARITY}, BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = \"" + name.trim().toLowerCase() + "\"", null,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Band band = getBandFromCursor(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return band;
}
```

But it always returns me a cursor with 0 length.
I tried to remove the quotes around the name, but after it query doent work.

Besides I tried to use a rawQuery, but the result is the same.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select * from " + BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_BANDS + " where band_name = \"" + name.trim().toLowerCase() + "\"", null);
```

UPDATE:

I tried single quotes:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_BANDS,
            new String[] {BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_POPULARITY}, BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = \'" + name.trim().toLowerCase() + "\'", null,
            null, null, null);
```

and

```
private long addBand(String bandName, String gender) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "\'" + bandName.trim().toLowerCase() + "\'");
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_POPULARITY, 1);
    values.put(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.COLUMN_GENDER, "");
    long insertId = database.insert(BandsSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_BANDS, null,
            values);

    return insertId;
}
```

As before insertion is ok, selection returns 0 rows.

Comment: In SQL, strings are delimited with single quotes, `'`, not double quotes, `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting the values, I doubt you need to put the double quotes around the values you insert since you specified in your DB Creation string that the fields are `TEXT`.

As for your rawQuery, try this:
`"SELECT * FROM " + BandsSQLiteOpenhelper.TABLE_BANDS + " WHERE band_name = '" + name.trim().toLowerCase() + "'";`

Try single quotes instead of double quotes when using Strings as identifiers in WHERE statements.

Comment: Thank you, selection with 'text' and insertion without quotes work.